# I need to get the value of the Marketo custom object

Tags: velocity, marketo, custom-object

I have developed a batch that retrieves our site's DB data and import into Marketo custom object with API. I tying to display this custom object’s value in the email body, but it is failing.

Script editor shows the custom object name but My token below returns no value.

```
$set($var = ${access_post_2_cList.get(0).title})
${var}
```

When I view the lead details, there is a Custom Objects tab, I can select the name of the custom object and see the records at there.

What did I leave to do?
Is this something about data type?
I am new to Marketo custom objects.

Comment: Which Version of Velocity are you using? What do `${access_post_2_cList}.class.name}` and `${access_post_2_cList.get(0).class.name}` display?

Comment: One of our member says it may be a one-to-many problem..
Version is Velocity 1.7、Tools 2.0、Java 6
The token just shows "$ {var}".